# Fundamental group contains $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Is there any topological space whose fundamental group contains $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? In case of (singular) homology or cohomology, we can change its coefficients to any abelian groups (with suitable modification, such as universal coefficient theorem). But for a fundamental group, I've never seen any space that has fundamental group $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$. I think it is impossible, but how to prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that, *as a group*, $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ is just the direct sum of an uncountable number of copies of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any group (including $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$) can be realized as the fundamental group of some space - in fact, for every group $G$, there is a two-dimensional CW complex with fundamental group $G$. See [Proposition 1.28 of Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) here.

Comment: (+1) For the record, an explicit not-too-hard-to-see construction of a space with fundamental group $\Bbb Q$ is the following homotopy colimit: take $\Bbb N$-many copies of $S^1 \times [0, 1]$, glue the front of the $k$-th copy to the end of the $(k+1)$-th copy by a degree $k$ map, for all $k$. So, e.g., running along the top of the $2$nd copy of the cylinder twice is homotopic to running along the front of the first cylinder once, i.e., that element represents $1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

Endow $Q$ with the discrete topology $Q_d$  and consider the classifying space corresponding to $Q_d$. Same construction with $R$.

Comment: If the OP knew what a classifying space was they wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: so i hope, he will learn it,by the way if op new the aswer of his question he would not have asked it